# PHP and SQL Server and column decryption

Tags: php, sql, password-hash

I have a PHP login form that has an encrypted column (EncryptedPwd) in SQL Server that uses a symmetric key and certificate to encrypt the column and I'm trying to query in PHP but the query fails.
The query is as below and it works in SQL Server:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY pwd_key DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE pwd select username,userType, CONVERT(varchar,DecryptByKey(EncryptedPwd)) AS DecryptedPwd
from <table>
where username = '$username' and usertype= 'T' and decryptedpwd = '$password'
```

But when I use the same in a PHP $query variable it fails.
If I use the below it works ok but this allows any username regardless of password to access:

```
select 'DecryptedPwd'=CONVERT(varchar,DecryptByKey(EncryptedPwd)) from <table> where username='$username' AND userType='T'
```

Any pointers would be great.

```
$query = "select * from <table> where password='$hashed_password' and username='$username";
$result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query, $array, $array2);
if (sqlsrv_num_rows ($result) > 0)
{
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
   {
      if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password))
      {
         $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
         header("location: access.php");
      }
      else
      {
            $error = "username or password is invalid";
      }
   }
}
else
{
   $error = "username or password is invalid";
}
```

In each scenario if I use the following code and query either $password or $hashed_password taking the respective value from the database I can login successfully:

```
    if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: access.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
```

Its just when I use the first piece of code access fails.

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but storing encrypted passwords isn't a good idea. Passwords should be _hashed_ (many times, and salted, ideally via a modern library that takes care of the details for you), not encrypted. Check out [`password_hash()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) from PHP's standard library. Switching to these functions should indirectly solve the problem you're currently facing while significantly increasing your security.

Comment: So nothing is done at the database level, it is all done in the PHP code? Thanks, I will give this a go.

Comment: What does "I cannot login to the application" mean? It might help if you [edit] your question and share your new code there instead of adding it in a comment. Also, what column type are you using to store the hashed password?

Comment: When you query it _how_? And, again, what column type are you using to store it? Please take my advice from my last comment and [edit] your question, adding the new code you are using.

Comment: I have a PHP login form that is querying the database in SQL Server. The data type is nvarchar. I will post the code accordingly.

Comment: @ThomRogers, did you attempt switching to Chris' suggestion. Hashing the password (not encrypting it) and comparing hashes. The difference is that an encrypted password can be decrypted and that's BAD. A hashed password can't be unhashed, but the hash can be compared.  The hashing happens on the PHP side, NOT in the database.

Comment: @ThomRogers, what is the size of the NVARCHAR column?

Comment: @JNevill, yes, I have tried the password hashing I am able to insert the hashed password into the database but when I try and run the password_verify as part of the login form I cannot access. If you refer to the original question I have added the code I am trying to run. I cant see why this isnt working currently. The nvarchar is 255. Thanks.

Comment: So your SQL query should be retreiving the hashed password stored in the database for the user you are trying to authenticate. Then you grab that hashedpassword from your retrieved results and use that in your password_verify function against the password that was supplied by the user.